# efficient way to add two binary string including padding if necessary in Java?

Tags: java, binary, char, addition

I am writing the code that returns the binary string  when two binaries are added together.
the first step involves checking if the length of two binary string is same, if not, pad them with '0' in the left side; eg : `00101 + 011001` should give `000101 + 011001` for padding;

I have written the code for this part. It works fine, but wondering if there is efficient way to achieve the same.

```
public class Common{

    public static void main(String[] args){


                //calling the addBinary will only print the padded binaries correctly   
        String result=addBinary("00101", "001010");
    }


public static String addBinary(String binary1, String binary2){

               String result - "";

        char[] bin1= binary1.toCharArray();
        char[] bin2=binary2.toCharArray();
        int[] bin1int=null;
        int[] bin2int=null;



        System.out.println("---------------before-----------------");

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bin1));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bin2));

        System.out.println("-----------------After---------------------");
        int bin1_len=bin1.length;
        int bin2_len=bin2.length;
        if (bin1_len<bin2_len){
            bin1int=new int[bin2_len];
            bin2int=new int[bin2_len];
            int j=bin2_len-bin1_len;
            for (char c: binary1.toCharArray()){    
                bin1int[j]=c-'0';
                j++;
                }   
        int k=0;
        for (char c: bin2 ){
            bin2int[k]=c-'0';
            k++;
        }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bin1int));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bin2int));

        //if (bin2_len<bin1_len)
        //reverse implementation of above;

                //yet to implement the addition calculation.

        return result;

    }
}
```

I am interested in efficient padding. Any tips/suggestions?

Comment: This question is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: There is a question in there as well which isn't about code review...

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I am not asking to review my code, but to come up with right way to pad strings for equal length.

Comment: @user1988876 Since your solution works, it is a right way. `codereview` can suggest improvements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
 // Read the binary string to integer and add the two together
 int total = Integer.parseInt(binary1, 2) + Integer.parseInt(binary2, 2);
 // Convert the resulting integer back to a binary string
 String str = new Integer(total).toBinaryString();
```

For more than 32 bits you will need to use Long.

If you really do want to pad the Strings just look at the two sizes and then left pad the shorter one with zeros to the length of the longer one.

```
String shorter, String longer;
if (binary1.length() < binary2.length) {
   shorter = binary1;
   longer = binary2;
} else {
   shorter = binary2;
   longer = binary1;
}
// Or any of the other multitude of ways to left pad a String.
shorter = org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.leftPad(smaller, larger.length(), '0')
```

Comment: Thanks, I know this method. but I am interested in padding with 0 so that I get equal length.

Comment: @user1988876 No worries about that - since the least significant digit is still the rightmost one, the result is the same with or without padding.

Comment: ...Unless you are more interested in just the two numbers, padded, and not the actual sum.

Comment: Why do things the complicated way? Even if you really must do the addition yourself just scan from the right doing it and the padding still isn't needed....

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for an efficient way to pad, I think the following would be a simpler and more efficient way.

```
    if (bin1_len<bin2_len){
        int j=bin2_len-bin1_len;
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0;i<j;i++){
            s.append('0');
        }
        s.append(binary1); //s now contains the 0 padded binary string
    }
```

Comment: I would *strongly* suggest that you look into how many instances of `String` you are creating with that method and consider the merits of `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @MichaelT Yes, thanks for pointing it out. I was a bit careless using a string instance where there might be numerous changes to it. StringBuilder is of course better for this case. I will edit this accordingly.

Comment: Better, you'll get better performance if you change the string `"0"` to the character `'0'`.  The string version needs to dig into the string to find out how big it is and then pull the character array out and do an array copy of that.  The `.append('0')` knows its a single character and just puts that value into the proper element in the backing array.

Comment: Compare: [append(char)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#AbstractStringBuilder.append%28char%29) and [append(String)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#AbstractStringBuilder.append%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: That I did not know. Thanks for the feedback.